# Masterdetailpage Xml returns Error : InitializeComponent Not found

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

i am fairly new to Android Development with C# and Xamarin. 
I have a problem, i am starting out using MasterDetailPage and now when I changed the xml for MasterDetailpage I am getting some very difficult time compiling the program to run successfully.

My code is looking like this :

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  x:Class="NavigationMasterDetail.MainPage">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <ContentPage Title="Menu">
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="bg.png" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                    <StackLayout Padding="0,20,0,0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                        <Image BorderColor="White" Source="profile.png" Aspect="AspectFill" WidthRequest="85" HeightRequest="85" />
                        <Label Text="Adam Pedley" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </Grid>
                <StackLayout Margin="20,20,20,0" Grid.Row="1" Spacing="15">
                    <ListView x:Name="navigationDrawerList" RowHeight="60" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="#e8e8e8" ItemSelected="OnMenuItemSelected">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <!-- Main design for our menu items -->
                                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="20,10,0,10" Spacing="20">
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </ContentPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage></NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Now the code behind looks like this  :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using xfMasterDetailNavigation.MenuItems;
using xfMasterDetailNavigation.Views;

namespace xfMasterDetailNavigation
{
    public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public List<MasterPageItem> menuList
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            menuList = new List<MasterPageItem>();
            // Adding menu items to menuList and you can define title ,page and icon  
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem()
            {
                Title = "Home",
                Icon = "homeicon.png",
                TargetType = typeof(HelloTest)
            });
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem()
            {
                Title = "Contact",
                Icon = "contacticon.png",
                TargetType = typeof(Information)
            });
            menuList.Add(new MasterPageItem()
            {
                Title = "About",
                Icon = "abouticon.png",
                TargetType = typeof(AboutMe)
            });
            // Setting our list to be ItemSource for ListView in MainPage.xaml  
            navigationDrawerList.ItemsSource = menuList;
            // Initial navigation, this can be used for our home page  
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(HelloTest)));
        }

        private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem;
            Type page = item.TargetType;
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
            IsPresented = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now here are the Errors i get :

```
1.) InitializeComponent() does not exist in current component
2.) navigationDrawerList does not exist in current component
3.) Property BorderColor was not found in type Image
```

Now I followed the step by step tutorial from here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dynamic-master-detail-page-in-xamarin-forms/

Now Please i want to know where i am getting it wrong. I am quite new to this

Answer (score 0):

I make the sample according to the tutorial.

> 1.) InitializeComponent() does not exist in current component

In my code, it works well. Maybe your project does not load well. Clean and rebuild. Try to run on device, if you could run this well, forget the error. It does not matter.

> 2.) navigationDrawerList does not exist in current component

navigationDrawerList has been defined in your MainPage listview. The same way, delete the obj and bin folder of project to clean and rebuild.

> 3.) Property BorderColor was not found in type Image

Delete this BorderColor Property of image control. This Image does not have the BorderColor property. Delete it, everything will be okay.

For more details, you could check the Image class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.image?view=xamarin-forms

I uploaded the code sample on GitHub, you could download from `Test1/XamarinDemo` folder to check it.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

[image]

Comment: Any update? Have you solved your problem? If the reply help you, do not forget to acept the answer.